# Wondering how to output a chart I saw in the economist magazine

Tags: r, ggplot2

I saw this in a recent economist and I was wondering if anyone has code that would help replicate it using ggplot. [Economist Chart](http://www.economist.com/node/17257797?story_id=17257797)

[image]
Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just use base R graphics? An horizontal `barplot` and `abline` will do the job.

Comment: How much of a replica do you want? I don't like it when people say "How can I replicate this?" without giving the level of detail. For example, do you need 'nil' on the US' zero point? All the dagger and double-dagger footnotes? The typeface? It would also be nice to have a starting point of your knowledge, such as "I know how to do a barplot in ggplot" (and maybe give an example) "but need some more advice on styling to produce something a bit like this".

Comment: You are right I should I have been clearer - but I really enjoy how people took this question to heart!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I played around a little using only base plot functionality. This is the result:

[image]

Here is the code that produced it:

```
bigmacprice <- data.frame(
    country = c("Switzerland", "Brazil", "Euro area",
        "Canada", "Japan", "United States",
        "Britain", "Singapore", "South Korea",
        "South Africa", "Mexico", "Thailand",
        "Russia", "Malaysia", "China"),
    price = c(6.78, 5.26, 4.79, 4.18, 3.91, 3.71,
              3.63, 3.46, 3.03, 2.79, 2.58, 2.44,
              2.39, 2.25, 2.18)
)


plotbigmac <- function(mac, base = "United States", xlim = c(-40, 100)) {
    mac <- mac[order(mac$price),]
    base = which(mac$country == base)
    height <- (mac$price / mac[base, "price"] - 1) * 100
    par(bg = "#d0e0e7", col.main = "#262324", col.axis = "#393E46",
        mar = c(8, 8, 6, 6), las = 1)
    barplot(height, width = .1, space = .4,
        names.arg = mac$country, #cex.names = .8,
        col = "#01516c", border = "#7199a8", # border = "#577784",
        horiz = TRUE, xlim = c(-40, 100), axes = FALSE)
    axis(3, lty = 0)
    title(main = "Bunfight\nBig Mac index", col = "#393E46")

    abline(v = seq(-100, 100, 10), col = "white", lwd = 2)
    abline(v = 0, col = "#c8454e", lwd = 2)
    par(xpd = TRUE)
    for (i in 1:nrow(mac)) {
        rect(105, (i - 1) / 7, 118, i / 7 - 0.05,
        col = "white", border = "#7199a8")
        text(112, (i - 1) / 7 + 0.05, mac$price[i], cex = 0.8, col = "#393E46")
    }
    rect(-120, 2.5, -90, 3, col = "#c8454e", border = "#c8454e")
    text(-68, -.2, "Sources:", col = "#393E46")
    text(-64, -.3, "McDonald's;", col = "#393E46")
    text(-60, -.4, "The Economist", col = "#393E46")
}

plotbigmac(bigmacprice)
```

It might not be the exact match (ex. i don't know how to right align without calling text directly), and if you try to resize it the text will jump around, so you would have to tweak the parameters further to fit your needs. But it goes to show that you can get far with using only basic plot functionality in R.

EDIT: As was commented, the white stripes cross the bars. This is inevitable and cant be adjusted with another call to `barplot` since that would redraw the plot area. Thus we have to take a peek into the source-code of `barplot` and customize it for this purpose (love how easy this is in R). But now we have moved outside of the comfy basics in R (i.e. using built in barplot). Here is another go at it:

```
plotBigMac <- function(mac, base = "United States") {
    old.par <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)
    on.exit(par(old.par))
    # Create data:
    mac <- mac[order(mac$price),]
    base = which(mac$country == base)
    height <- (mac$price / mac[base, "price"] - 1) * 100
    # Costume 'barplot'
    NN <- length(height)
    width <- rep(1, length.out = NN)
    delta <- width / 2
    w.r <- cumsum(width + 0.5)
    w.m <- w.r - delta
    w.l <- w.m - delta
    xlim <- c(range(-.01 * height, height)[1], 100)
    ylim <- c(min(w.l), max(w.r))
    par(bg = "#d0e0e7", col.main = "#262324", col.axis = "#393E46",
        mar = c(8, 8, 6, 6), las = 1, cex = 0.9)
    plot.new()
    plot.window(xlim, ylim)
    abline(v = seq(-100, 100, 20), col = "white", lwd = 2)
    rect(0, w.l, height, w.r, col = "#01516c", border = "#7199a8", lwd = 1)

    # Lines and axis
    abline(v = 0, col = "#c8454e", lwd = 2)
    axis(3, axTicks(3), abs(axTicks(3)), lty = 0)
    axis(2, labels = mac$country, at = w.m, lty = 0)

    # Move outside of plot area
    par(xpd = TRUE)

    # Text misc.
    text(5, (w.l[base] + w.r[base]) / 2, "nil", font = 3)
    text(8, w.r[NN] + 2.3, "+")
    text(-8, w.r[NN] + 2.3, "-")

    # Create price boxes:
    rect(105, w.l, 125, w.r,
        col = "white", border = "#7199a8", lwd = 1)
    text(115, (w.r + w.l)/2, mac$price, cex = 0.8, col = "#393E46")

}
```

Which creates this:

[image]

Comment: Sweet. But it needs the white lines under the bars, which is tricky because barplot establishes the plot and puts the bars in and then you cant put things under them. Does barplot have a type='n' option so you can set the axes etc, then add the lines, then add the bars with an add=TRUE parameter? Or maybe the lines could be drawn as extended tick marks...

Comment: Can get round this by doing the barplot as normal, splatting the white lines over it, then doing barplot again but with add=TRUE parameter.

Answer (score 9):

The [latticeExtra](http://cran.r-project.org/package=latticeExtra) package has a *theme* styled after [The Economist](http://www.economist.com) magazine which should help as a start.

However, that uses [lattice](http://cran.r-project.org/package=lattice) whereas all the kids these days clamor for [ggplot2](http://cran.r-project.org/package=ggplot2) ...

Comment: +1 for callin me a kid. that feels good. Will check latticeExtra though... actually never heard of the Extra

Comment: Call me an old pharte, but I still like base graphics and lattice.

Comment: latticeExtra is largely by Felix Andrews who has done wonderful work with extension to lattice --- see his packages playwith and latticist.  But as I bemoaned earlier, kids these days have eyes only for Hadley.

Comment: If you want to get great advice on lattice, just restrict your searches in the r-help archives to "Sarkar|Felix|Murrell".

Comment: The `ggthemes` package, based on `ggplot2` has The Economist theme too

Answer (score 3):

I think the best (quickest, easiest) way to achieve precise typesetting of an R graphic is to use basic R functions to produce the main detail (use ggplot with geom_bar in this case, or base graphics barplot) and then save the plot to an SVG file. Open the SVG in your favourite editing package (Inkscape impresses me more every time I use it) and then do the final typesetting there.

You can then do things like grab a legend and move it around, delete elements, add text anywhere with any formatting in any font etc.

Comment: This contradicts reproducibility principle. You and others wouldn't be able to recreate your plot.

Comment: Not sure about Inkscape but you can programmatically edit images using the GIMP. http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/

Comment: As evidenced by this question, The Economist's plot also violates the reproducibility principle.  So to stay faithful to the original, the reproduction should also be unreproducible.

Comment: Huh? We simply don't have their script. What makes you think this cannot be automated?  That had been outed as R users (just like the NY Times graphics department).

Comment: +1 for inkscape. I don't agree about reproducibility. Using Inkscape (or any other graphic software) to graphically enhance the plot does not prevent anyone to remake the plot (having the dataset of course). You could do the plot in yellow instead of blue, as long as you have the dataset the plot is reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

```
bigmacprice=rnorm(10)  

names(bigmacprice)=1:10

par(bg="lightblue")
barplot(sort(bigmacprice),
         horiz=T,
         legend="Bunfight!! \nBigmac index \nyadda \nyadda \nmmnnnkay ",
         args.legend = list(  x = "topleft",
                             bty="n"

                            ),
  col='darkblue'
)
```

Comment: This is not exactly a replicate... I'd use text() by the way instead of abusing the legend. If I run it (R2.11.1), the text floating over the bars. Don't think this is what OP had in mind...